# How to put a progress bar between 2 fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've one main activity which is hosting a fragment.
one fragment in the activity navigate to the 2nd fragment, i want to put a progress bar with a spinner style when i replacing from fragment 1 to fragment 2, cause it takes time to the 2nd fragment to be loaded completely.

Answer (score 3):

You should implement an interface (lets say, `ProgressActivityListener`) with 2 callbacks in the parent activity: `showProgressBar` and `hideProgressBar`. Then when the the first fragment goes to show the second fragment, before starting the transition call

`((ProgressActivityListener) getActivity()).showProgressBar()`

and when the second fragment is finished loading call

`((ProgressActivityListener) getActivity()).hideProgressBar()` from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an async task which will run in the background and will update the progress bar. Call execute method before navigation starts, and return a variable to allow it happen. 
There are numerous examples over the internet about async task implementing progress bars.
For example :
http://www.concretepage.com/android/android-asynctask-example-with-progress-bar